# How to Sync data from SQL database field type(nvarchar) to Dynamics CRM field type (Lookup)

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization, dynamics-crm, lookup

I am trying to sync data from an SQL Server to Dynamics CRM.

I had created a solution/project in C#. Where syncing an account entity of CRM, all the details like name, account number, ship date, phone number all this kind of detail are successfully syncing because form SQL, the data type is `nvarchar` or `int` and in CRM it is a single line of text.

But while I am doing the same sync from `nvarchar` to a lookup field of CRM it is not working and the exception occurs.

Here, the account is the name of the entity in CRM and SalesContact is name of the field from SQL and data type is `nvarchar` and ppg_salescontact is the name of the field in CRM and data type is lookup.

```
  Entity enAccount = new Entity("account");

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(drRowAccount["SalesContact"] + "")) { enAccount["ppg_salescontact"] = 
 SecurityElement.Escape(drRowAccount["SalesContact"].ToString().Trim()); }
```

> Exception :" Message : Error converting attribute value to Property:
>   Attribute [ppg_salescontact], Attribute type [lookup] of Entity
>   [account] with value of type [System.String]:
>   [System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference'. "

Please suggest me what can I do for this.

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? if so, please mark it as accepted by ticking the V to its left. if not, let me know and I'll try to further help you.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you get says it all: You can't assign a value whose type is `string` to a field whose type is `EntityReference`.

So, to get an `EntityReference` based on that `string`, what you must do is take your `string` value, and based on this value, query the CRM to get the appropriate CRM record. Specifically, you need to query the CRM entity whose `ppg_salescontact` is the lookup for.

The result of this query would be of a type that derives from `Entity`, which you can then turn into `EntityReference` (by calling `ToEntityReference()`).

For example, if `ppg_salescontact` is a lookup for the CRM `Contact` entity, and if `drRowAccount["SalesContact"]` gives you the full name of the contact, then you can query it as follows (that's LINQ syntax):

```
Contact contact = orgContext
   .ContactSet
   .Where(c => c.FullName == drRowAccount["SalesContact"])
   .FirstOrDefault();
EntityReference contactRef = contact?.ToEntityReference();
```